# Clearing the screen with os.system("cls") dosn't work with socket

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, os.system

So I was making a Python Multiplayer Ascii Game and I needed to clear the Frame for the Game, but when I want to use `os.system('cls')` it just does nothing.

```
import socket,time
import subprocess as sp
import keyboard,os

def Main(k):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect(("127.0.0.1",8000))
    while True:
        for Key,Command in k.items():
            if keyboard.is_pressed(Key):
                exec(Command)

        data = s.recv(2048).decode()
        data = data.replace("PlaceHolder","")
        lastdata = data
        s.send("-".encode())

        if not data == "":
            print(data+"\n"*2)
        elif data != "" and lastdata == "":
            sp.call('cls')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    keydict = {"w":'s.send("w".encode())',
               "d":'s.send("d".encode())',
               "a":'s.send("a".encode())',
               "s":'s.send("s".encode())',
               "esc":'exit()'}
    Main(keydict)
```

Comment: Is this being run on a windows machine?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Windows @mypetlion

Comment: What does clearing the screen have to do with sockets?

Comment: It's "just a loop with socket code" that doesn't work.  Show code.

Comment: Updated Code...

Comment: @RemyLebeau I have a Single Player Ascii Game without socket and `os.system('cls')` works, but know with socket it doesn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did mistakes in my Code and fixed them. 
    Old:

```
if not data == "":
        print(data+"\n"*2)
    elif data != "" and lastdata == "":
        sp.call('cls')
```

New:

```
if not data == "":
        os.system("CLS")
        print(data+"\n"*2)
        time.sleep(0.05)
```

So i deleted the usless if Statement because it just didn't trigger os.system("CLS")